# Duplicate component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a navbar component in my AppComponent but I don't know why navbar component is duplicated.

I've only navbar

[image: AppComponent]

navbar duplicated

[image: View]

Comment: Generally the app.component is who have the navBar, the navBar is not routed in anywhere and is not inside any more component else the app.component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your app.component.html file by following code

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

You might have added navbar-component into your routing file that is why angular rending first navbar from  selector another rendering from .

Hope you get your solution,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the app-navbar from your app.component.html. Then go to your app.routing.module.ts file and insert the following snippet in your const routes: Routes = []

```
  {
   path: '',
   redirectTo: 'navbar',
   pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
   path: '',
   component: NavbarComponent
  },
```

OR

```
  {
   path: '',
   component: NavbarComponent
  },
```

Comment: Really **not**, Generally the app.component is who have the navBar, the navBar is not routed in anywhere and is not inside any more component else the app.component